Android: Change Display name for PDF file when Opened
I am trying to open a PDF file named external_source.pdf from the res/raw folder in Android Studio and display its name as External Source.pdf.Currently with the below the title of the pdf file when opened is coming as external_source.pdf. I tried passing the display name as  External Source.pdf but then the file itself is not opening.  How to fix it in the below code
Below is the code
    fun fetchPdfFile(
    context: Context,
    resourceId: Int,
    fileName: String,
    errorMessage: String
) {
    try {
        val inputStream = context.resources.openRawResource(resourceId)
        val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName)
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var length: Int
        while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length)
        }
        outputStream.flush()
        outputStream.close()
        inputStream.close()
        val fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, Endpoints.FILE_PROVIDER, file)
        val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
            .getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.toString()))
        if (mimeType != null) {
            IntentManager().openPdfFile(context, fileUri, mimeType)
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(context, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

Call this function like below
fetchPdfFile(
                context,
                R.raw.external_source,
                "external_source.pdf",
                context.getString(R.string.open_file_error)
            )

